# PasteSpecial using Ole,PowerPoint,Delphi

Tags: delphi, ole, powerpoint-2007

How do you use PasteSpecial in Delphi to paste into an Ole PowerPoint. I have rtf data i want to paste into powerpoint and I need to use PasteSpecial. However I cannot find documentation on how to fill out the parameters it needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PasteSpecial is just going to favor one format over the other. So you can prioritize the formats, or eliminate formats, to influence the pasting. For example, if you have RTF and TEXT on the clipboard, and PP always pastes TEXT by default, even if RTF is listed first, then you could just eliminate TEXT and provide ONLY RTF. Then it has to paste as RTF.

Answer (score 0):

MSDN has documentation for the [2003](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa212207(v=office.11).aspx) and [2007](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb251389(v=office.12).aspx) versions. In both cases, the first parameter should be `ppPasteRTF` if you want to choose the clipboard contents with RTF format. You can use `EmptyParam` for the remaining five parameters.